# Error While Get Sum of Entity Property from Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data

I've made a class to manage my `CoreData` entities [named : DBHelper] (All CRUD operations, which works fine. However, I need to get the sum of a property called subtotal but I'm receiving the following error:

```
thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)
```

What is wrong with my code ?

Entity class

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Odetails)
public class Odetails: NSManagedObject {
    public let entityName = "Odetails"
}
```

Entity Extension :

```
extension Odetails {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Odetails> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Odetails>(entityName: "Odetails")
    }

    @NSManaged public var pname: String?
    @NSManaged public var price: Int16?
    @NSManaged public var qty: Int16?
    @NSManaged public var subtotal: Int16?

}
```

Core Data Helper Class  :

```
import CoreData

class DBHelper {


    var context: NSManagedObjectContext

    init(context: NSManagedObjectContext){
        self.context = context
}

    // ......


    func getsum() -> Int16{
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Odetails")
        do {
            let response = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            var sum : Int16 = 0
            for res in response as! [Odetails]{
                sum +=  res.subtotal
            }
            return sum
        } catch let error as NSError {
            // failure
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return 0
        }
    }


}
```

The Use  :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    let dbhelper = DBHelper(context: context)
    print("count : \(dbhelper.getAll().count)")
    print("Sum : \(dbhelper.getsum())")    //  ERROR HERE
    var sum : Int16 = 0
    for r in dbhelper.getAll() {  // Method Return [Odetails]

        sum += r.subtotal      // OR ERROR HERE

    }
    print(" Sum : \(sum)")
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: In which line does the crash occur?

Comment: Please check my use code, if i use the get sum method or if i use another method that returns [Odetails] and loop through to get the sum (in both cases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than forcing unwrapping. Can you try optional binding to make sure that the data was being fetched correctly.

```
guard let response: [Odetails] = context.fetch(fetchRequest) else { return 0}
var sum = 0
for res in response {
    sum = sum + Int(res.subtotal)
}
return sum
```

The problem is you got overflow on `Int16`. According to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

> In most cases, you don’t need to pick a specific size of integer to
>   use in your code. Swift provides an additional integer type, Int,
>   which has the same size as the current platform’s native word size:
>
> On a 32-bit platform, Int is the same size as Int32. On a 64-bit
>   platform, Int is the same size as Int64.
>
> Unless you need to work with a specific size of integer, always use
>   Int for integer values in your code. This aids code consistency and
>   interoperability. Even on 32-bit platforms, Int can store any value
>   between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647, and is large enough for many
>   integer ranges.

Comment: same error ! and yes i'm sure that the data is fetching correctly check my use `dbhelper.getAll()` this function returns [Odetails] even if i loop through it i'm getting the same error !!

Comment: if i print `res.subtotal` it will print all the values with no errors

Comment: Ok, we can narrow it down. The issue absolutely is `Int16`. I've edited my answer. Could you please try again?

Comment: Wow, its work now !! please could you explain more why its related to `Int16` ?

Comment: Forced unwrapping is 100% safe in this case because the fetch request is distinct. You can even write `NSFetchRequest<Odetails>(entityName: "Odetails")` without any type cast (nor type annotation).

Comment: No worries. I will recheck regarding to forcing unwrapping NSFetchRequest

Answer (score 4):

A bit offtopic, this is a more efficient way to get the sum of a particular property in Core Data

```
func getSum() -> Int16
{
    let description = NSExpressionDescription()
    description.name = "sumSubtotal"
    description.expression = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "@sum.subtotal")
    description.expressionResultType = .integer16AttributeType
    let request : NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Odetails")
    request.propertiesToFetch = [description]
    request.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(request)
        return results.isEmpty ? 0 : results[0]["sumSubtotal"] as! Int16
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return 0
    }
}
```